# How to compare two wave audio files and generate score?

Tags: java, audio, audio-fingerprinting, musicg

**What I tried:**
I try to compare(fingerprint) two audio songs(with out background music) by using [musicg](https://code.google.com/archive/p/musicg/) API.

**The code is like below:**
file1.wav is master file and file2.wav (vice-versa) is recorded file, both are sung by same person(without background music) and same song.

```
     FingerprintSimilarity siml = new Wave("file1.wav")
                                    .getFingerprintSimilarity(new Wave("file2.wav"));
     System.out.println(siml.getScore());
```

But it's not comparing the two files properly and getting very low score(0.099384) even though two songs are sung by same person and same way.

How can I solve this Issue? 
Any other java API will help to do the same?

Comment: Is it the same recording?

Comment: @ostrichofevil, two recordings (one is taken as master file second one is recording) sung by same person.

Comment: You're getting a low score for the same reason that Shazam doesn't work for different recordings: even though they sound the same to the ear, the waveforms are actually pretty different at a small enough level.

Comment: @ostrichofevil, thank you for reply.
do you mean If a person sing same song two times and when we compare both wave files they will be different? (we won't get minimum score?)

Comment: @ChandraSekhar yeah it is completly if the same person sing it twice, for this case fingerprints is not the way, maybe do you need build a set of audio features(Pitch, Chroma) to compare.